# Is there any way to integrate Zabbix with Webhook?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I want to get Openshift(OCP) alerts on Zabbix. OCP supports Webhook integration to send data. Is there any way to send data to Zabbix via Webhook?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No (as of Zabbix 5), you need to build your own webhook-to-zabbix connector, but it's fairly simple, using the already existing libraries available for most languages. Example: https://github.com/gmauleon/alertmanager-zabbix-webhook